# IE11 shows newly added element only after some random click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, ng-show

I have a realy confusing problem with IE 11.

I use AngularJS to fill an element and display the element afterwards.
It works perfectly in FireFox and Google Chrome. In IE11 it wouldn't show until I click somewhere. It doesn't matter where I click. It could be somewhere on the page itself or my windows taskbar or on my second monitor.
I don't get any javascript errors on the console. After the random click IE shows at first only blank HTML. The styling is applied a moment later.

EDIT:
My Porblem is super strange. I've never seen something like this bug. My Code is running perfectly. All elements are thier with right values at the right place. All CSS rules should be applied. The pagination shows only after a completly random click somewhere but this only happens in IE11. Every other browser works like a charm.

Have any body saw this before?
I've asked two ather web devellopers in my company and we did code reviews but can't find any bugs in the code. 
We think it's an IE11 bug. But there seems to be no one that can confirm this.

Comment: You should add a [mcve]

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem, you should add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, so that we could test your code on our side, it might be easier for us to help you solve the problem. Besides, this is [an example of how to implement pagination in AngularJS](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/01/31/angularjs-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google), you could refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $scope.apply and surround your scope change statements with $scope.apply.

```
$scope.$on("showPaging", function(){
    $scope.apply(function() {
        $scope.showPaging = true;
    }
});
```

The use of $scope.apply is not encouraged though.